# App crashes if unexpected payload is received in RestKit (version 0.1)

Tags: restkit

I am using Version 0.1 and fetching data using loadObjectsAtResourcePath:usingBlock: and loadObjectsAtResourcePath:delegate: methods. The mapping to be used is set using setObjectMapping:forKeyPath: method on the mappingProvider property of object manager.

Now, if the data comes in the format that the mapping provider expects, things go well. However, if it is not in the format the app just crashes. On debugging, I found that the 'if [self isResponseMappable]' check in RKObjecLoader.m method is the last executed line before the crash happens.

Here is an example. If a JSON such as this comes things go well - {"topic_details":""}

However, if this JSON comes the app crashes - ["Access Denied"]

Here is the mapping key path specified -
[objectManager.mappingProvider setObjectMapping:topicMapping forKeyPath:@"topic_details"]

How can this be dealt with, there is nothing to stop the web service from returning unexpected data. It is a serious issue.

Would moving to a later version help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved to RestKit 0.2 pre-release 3. It has been a lot better so far.